# Magento2 NodeJS: SOAP or REST API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, soap-api-v2, http-request, post-data

Does anyone know a good module that can use HTTP VERBS like POST and PUT ?. I tried this one [magento2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-magento2) but only managed to use GET and DELETE ...

Hope someone has a few ideas !

Comment: This may help  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-magento2

Comment: this is an old post, it took two years for someone to reply :) I'm not even into Magento anymore :)